# Assembly code, loop amount with variable value?

Tags: loops, assembly

i'm struggling with learning assembly code so please don't hate me if this is a stupid question..
I'm trying to understand how to do loops, I have learned that to loop you use the following structure:

```
        mov ECX, 3
    l1:
          <loop body?
        loop l1
```

however, instead of 3 im trying to load the value of a variable (called 'first') however when I do this, it just seems to loop infinitely. This is the current code i've got:

```
    lea eax, get1; ask for the first number
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 4

        lea eax, first; read it in
        push eax
        lea eax, format
        push eax
        call scanf
        add esp, 8

        mov ECX, first
    l1:
    /* test loop body */
    lea eax, get1; ask for the first number
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 4
        loop l1
```

does anyone know where i'm going wrong?

Comment: What is ECX value after printf call?

Comment: `ECX` is a _caller-saved_ register, so you cannot assume that its value won't be changed by `printf`.

Comment: `mov ECX, first` loads `ECX` with the address of `first`, not with the value stored at that address. You probably want `mov ECX, [first]`.

Comment: This would be true if it were Nasm syntax, but it is not (or the `lea`s wouldn't assemble).